# RestKit: how to define optional (nested) keypaths

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I've a JSON-structure like

```
{
   "objects":{
      "person":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"my name"
            "contacts":{
               "address":{
                  "id":"1",
                  "street":"mystreet",
                  "country":"mycountry"
               },
               "email":{
                  "id":"1",
                  "emailAddress":"hello@hello.com"
               }
            },
         },
...
```

and I'm trying to map it the following way:

```
[personMapping mapKeyPath:@"contacts.address" toRelationship:@"address" withMapping:addressMapping];
```

This works well as long as contacts is existing. But if there's no address/email, then this element isn't sent, which leads to an exception in `RKMappingOperation#applyRelationshipMappings`: value = [self.sourceObject valueForKeyPath:relationshipMapping.sourceKeyPath];

Right now, my workaround is to use `@try...@catch`, but I hope there's a better solution for this...

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**: The exception happens then if no contacts are sent at all; then, the JKDictionary looks like this (again in `RKMappingOperation#applyRelationshipMappings`):

```
{
    contacts = "";
    name = myName;
    id = 1;
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is the exception being thrown? also, which RestKit version do you use?

Comment: @mja: version 0.9.3, the exception is `[<__NSCFConstantString 0x3fe1bc> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key address.`

Comment: I tried similar case in one of my RestKit based project and i get no exception whatsoever. I use latest RestKit from git, master branch, though. Please try the following (to check if you get the same exception): add a relationship mapping to non-existant key, eg. "contacts.whatever" (keep all your mappings unchanged) and parse JSON that contains both address and email.

Comment: @mja thanks for your comment; please see my edit... I think we're on a good way :)

Comment: i'd suggest you to try the latest git/master branch.

Comment: will you try to set setNilForMissingRelationships to "YES"? http://restkit.org/api/0.9/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html#//api/name/setNilForMissingRelationships

Comment: it's a relationshipmapping, so there's no way to set that flag. on the mapping itself it's already set, but without effect in that direction.

Comment: oh, just one more idea. The problematic JSON, is the "contacts" element missing completely, or is it empty?

Comment: the element is missing completely in the JSON.

Comment: do you think you can create a minimal app that shows the problem & send it over to me? I failed to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should properly initialise your objects when you instantiate them? Maybe start out with all your properties zero; then as you go along fill out properties; and before you commit (or map or whatever), check the data integrity of your property values..